# Magento 2 : Error when trying to create invoice

Tags: magento2, shipping, invoice

When trying to create invoice for order placed with bank transfer payment i got this error with message the order status is changed successfully but the order status still pending any explanation please.

> **Error Message : We can't save the invoice right now**

[image: nvoi]

Comment: check, system.log and exception.log

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213665/we-cant-save-the-invoice-right-now

Comment: there is nothing in exception log